# Raster multiplication script not executing

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, error-000732, map-algebra

I built this code to multiply rasters but it will not execute, it gives me the following error: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset in_raster1 does not exist or is not supported

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy 
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = outRas = "P:\del\New Folder\new" 

# Local variables:
in_raster1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
in_raster2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
in_raster2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

# Process: Raster Calculator
outRas = Raster("in_raster1") * Raster("in_raster2")* Raster("in_raster3")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inputting your variables as string. Try without the quotes.

```
outRas = Raster(in_raster1) * Raster(in_raster2) * Raster(in_raster3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save outRas:

```
    outRas.save("Multiplication_Raster")
```

pd: GetParameterAsText should start with 0, not 1 as you have.